# Getting output from a query with an implode function in it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I'm trying to determine whether a combination of topics related to a forum is unique. This is done while adding topics to a forum. The uniqueness is checked with this code and query:

```
$options = array(); //here's your choices
$options[] = 'blablabla';
$options[] = 'blabla';

foreach($options as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; 
    }

$sql_unique = "SELECT Forums_ForumID, list
           FROM (
         SELECT Forums_ForumID, GROUP_CONCAT( Topics_TopicID ) AS list
         FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM Topics_crosstable
            ORDER BY Topics_TopicID
         )H
         GROUP BY Forums_ForumID
            )A
            WHERE list = (
         SELECT GROUP_concat( TopicID )
         FROM Topics
         WHERE Name IN (";
$sql_unique .= implode(",",$options);
$sql_unique .= ") ORDER BY Forums_ForumID ASC )";

$result = mysql_query($sql_unique);
//print "$result";
//echo $result;
//echo mysql_num_rows($result);
//$assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

var_dump($result);
```

I'm sure the query works fine when using fixed values in WHERE. With the current code I can't get any output. The vardump gives a result 'false' no matter if the combination of topics is unique or not. I've been trying for days now, so I really help you can help me out!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your values in the `$options` array are strings, so you have to quote them before inserting into your SQL string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote your options if they are strings.

```
$sql_unique .= "'". implode("','", $options) ."'";
```

Comment: However I should do this indeed, I'm still not able to get the output I'm after. The result is now 'resource(4) of type (mysql result)' or 'Resource id #4' when echoing, no matter what the input from the array is.

Comment: Fixed it by adding:
if(!$res = mysql_query($sql_unique))
{
    trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql);
}
//elseif(mysql_num_rows($sql_unique) == 0)
//{
  //  echo 'Geen resultaten gevonden';
//}
else
{
    
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   
if(!$row)
{
            
   echo 'The combination of topics is unique';   
}
else
{
  echo $row['list'].'<br />';  
  
}

}